# Handling facebook crawler in mean-seo when html5 mode is on

Tags: angularjs, facebook, meanjs

I have a meanjs application and I have implemented [mean-seo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mean-seo) to handle the crawlers. I plan to deploy the app in HTML5 mode.

The documentation for mean-seo says that I should put this meta tag to be able to run in html5 mode

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

which I have done.

I understand that google and bing bots now support AJAX sites and do not need any support for crawling. But having gone through quite a few threads, I have read that facebook bots have to be handled specifically.

I found setups for nginx and apache servers for independent Angular JS apps, but I could not find any resources for doing so in a MEAN setup. How do I handle facebook bots to work with mean-seo here?

Thanks